# Powershell : You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression

Tags: powershell

Currently in the process of building a script that gathers guests from AzureAD and gives us a breakdown of how many days since the last login.

When i run the [int]**** line solo it works fine, however when I run within the ForEach i get teh error

```
At line:8 char:5
+     [int]$LogonAge = [math]::Round(($Today - ($LastLogon.CreatedDateT ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

The script is below:

```
$Users = Get-AzureADUser | Where-Object {$_.UserType -eq 'Guest' -and $_.AccountEnabled -eq 'True' } | Select AccountEnabled,DisplayName,ObjectID,UserType
$Today = Get-Date
$DaysOld = 30

    ForEach ($User in $Users) {
    $ObjectID = $User.ObjectId
    $LastLogon = Get-AzureADAuditSignInLogs -Top 1 -Filter "UserID eq '$ObjectID'" | select CreatedDateTime 
    [int]$LogonAge = [math]::Round(($Today - ($LastLogon.CreatedDateTime).ToDateTime($null)).TotalDays)
            if ($LogonAge -gt 30) {
            Set-AzureADUser -ObjectID $user.ObjectID -AccountEnabled $true
}
}
```

Any idea what im doing wrong?

Comment: Modified to show the full code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check for nullability and then operate.

```
$Users = Get-AzureADUser | Where-Object {$_.UserType -eq 'Guest' -and $_.AccountEnabled -eq 'True' } | Select AccountEnabled,DisplayName,ObjectID,UserType
$Today = Get-Date
$DaysOld = 30

    ForEach ($User in $Users) {
    $ObjectID = $User.ObjectId
    $LastLogon = Get-AzureADAuditSignInLogs -Top 1 -Filter "UserID eq '$ObjectID'" | select CreatedDateTime 
    if( $LastLogon -ne $null) # check for nullability 
    {
    [int]$LogonAge = [math]::Round(($Today - ($LastLogon.CreatedDateTime).ToDateTime($null)).TotalDays)
            if ($LogonAge -gt 30) {
            Set-AzureADUser -ObjectID $user.ObjectID -AccountEnabled $true
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate,

Appreciate it, that worked a treat.

Comment: @AndrewWaters, if it worked. mark it as answer. So, it will be helpful for others in future.

Comment: @AndrewWaters, glad to note that it worked.